# inserting single node to linked list giving me circular at the next value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list, insert, jestjs

inserting single node to linked list giving me circular  at the next value !!

hello there , i am learning how to create a linked list and test it with jest , 
as you can see in the photo my issue that its not stopping , from my understanding it should giving me a null at the end !
[this how my conole.log looks like !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZvbd.png)

my test file :

```html
'use strict' ;


const LL = require('../lib/linked-list.js');


describe('Linked-List Test' , () => {

  it('Can properly insert into the linked list' , () => {
    let list = new LL() ;
    list.insert('test');
    expect(list.head.name).toEqual('test');
  });

});
```

my js file :

```js
'use strict';

// const Node = require

function Node(value) {
  this.name = value;
  this.next = null;
}



class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  insert(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);
    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = node;
    }
    // { name : test1 , next = null }

    let pointer = this.head;
    console.log(pointer);
    console.log(pointer.next);
    while (pointer.next) {
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }
    console.log(node);
    pointer.next = node;
    console.log(pointer.next);
    console.log(pointer.next.next);
    console.log(pointer.next.next.next);
    console.log(pointer.next.next.next.next);

    return this;
  }


   


  include(value){

    let pointer = this.head;
    while (pointer.next) {
      if(pointer.next.name === value){
        return true ;
      }
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }

    return false ;
  }






}

module.exports = LinkedList;
```

Comment: Your -> `if (!this.head) {`  maybe needs a return, otherwise your going to add to yourself later in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You have to add return in `if (!this.head)` condition. So it should not execute the code after this block.

```js
"use strict";

// const Node = require

function Node(value) {
  this.name = value;
  this.next = null;
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  insert(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);
    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = node;
      return this;
    }

    let pointer = this.head;
    while (pointer.next) {
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }

    pointer.next = node;
    return this;
  }

  include(value) {
    let pointer = this.head;
    while (pointer.next) {
      if (pointer.next.name === value) {
        return true;
      }
      pointer = pointer.next;
    }

    return false;
  }
}


let list = new LinkedList();
list.insert("test");
list.insert("test2");
console.log(list);
```